# Extract the second word from a string in ODI Expression

Tags: sql, oracle, substring, oracle-data-integrator

This two syntaxes allow to get the scond word from a string in oracle

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('Hello this is an example', '\s+(\w+)\s') AS syntax1,
       SUBSTR('Hello this is an example', 
              INSTR('Hello this is an example', ' ', 1, 1) + 1, 
              INSTR('Hello this is an example', ' ', 1, 2) 
              - INSTR('Hello this is an example', ' ', 1)
       ) AS syntax2 
  FROM dual;
```

**Result:**

```
syntax1  syntax2
-------  -------
this     this
```

---

I'm working in ODI (oracle data integration), this two syntaxes doesn't work in ODI:
For ODI, the regexp is not valid and INSTR function accepts only 2 parameters

Can you suggest me a solution that can work in ODI?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly used this expression:

```
SELECT 
          SUBSTR (
             SUBSTR ('one two three four',
                     INSTR ('one two three four', ' ') + 1,
                     999999),
             0,
               INSTR (
                  SUBSTR ('one two three four',
                          INSTR ('one two three four', ' ') + 1,
                          999999),
                  ' ')
             - 1)
  FROM DUAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Then, you can apply `SUBSTR()` function twice :

```
WITH t2(str) AS
(
 SELECT SUBSTR( TRIM( str ), INSTR( TRIM( str ), ' ') + 1, LENGTH( TRIM(str) ) )              
   FROM t --> original table
)   
SELECT SUBSTR( str, 1, INSTR(str, ' ') - 1 ) AS extracted_string           
  FROM t2

extracted_string
----------------
this
```

If the version of installed **ODI** is *12+*, then you can also use `REGEXP_REPLACE()` as below one :

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '(\w+)\s(\w+)( .*)', '\2' ) AS extracted_string
  FROM t
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e7cb2462e0c49953339cccfedd867329)</kbd>

Comment: I'm working on ODI 12.1.3, don't accepts regular expressions . Thank your for your answer it's OK when I use it in procedure ODI but I need expression for attribut

Comment: Hı @Ruby I know it doesn't support REGEXP_SUBSTR(), but should support REGEXP_REPLACE(). Have you tried the both cases within the answer..?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should support `' [[:alpha:]]+ '`